# Нужно данные из textbox'ов на form2 передать в dataGridView1 на form1

Tags: c#, winforms

Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();     
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Form2 form = new Form2();
       form.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 Form1 = null;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text + " "), (textBox2.Text + " "), (textBox3.Text + " "),
            textBox4.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: у тебя код только от 1 формы

Comment: Исправил, теперь от двух форм

Comment: И в чем проблема? Объявите в Form2 требуемые поля, и какой-нить метод public void Init(params...), в котором берете требуемые данные из аргументов Init'а и настраиваете грид. После вызова конструктора делаете вызов form.Init(bla1, bla2, ... ) и потом ShowDialog().

Comment: И еще... Нужно данные из textbox'ов на form1 передать в dataGridView1 на form2 ... грид на Form2, а Вы делаете Form1.dataGridView1... Определитесь уж. Или вопрос подкорректируйте или с ...   Form1.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text + " "), (textBox2.Text + " "), (textBox3.Text + " "), textBox4.Text); - у Вас тут явно одной скобки не хватает где-то ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для изменения `dataGridView1` находящийся в `Form1` вы можете отправить её в конструктор `Form2` для дальнейшего изменения, или отправить сразу всю `Form1`.

Пример при отправки всей формы:

Form1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form2 = new Form2(this); // где this - Form1
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Form2:

```
Form1 form1;
public Form2(Form1 form1)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.form1 = form1;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form1.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text);
}
```

В случае отправки всей формы не забудьте в `Form1` для `dataGridView1` добавить модификатор public:
[image]

Comment: Я не могу разобрать что куда вставлять

Comment: у меня textBox'сы во втором формс

Comment: @ВинченцоПетренко только сейчас правильно понял вопрос), ответ исправил, так же проверьте свою строчку `Form1.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text + " "), (textBox2.Text + " "), (textBox3.Text + " "), textBox4.Text);`, как-то многовато скобочек, мб попробуйте как в ответе